# searchBar textDidChange

Tags: iphone, ios5, searchbar

In my tableViewController with a searchBar I am using the following method:

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText 
{
   ...my code
}
```

and it works fine when I type text directly into the searchBar.

The problem I have now is that I want to invoke this method programatically - meaning that I want to fill in the search bar from my code which I know how to do (actually I am selecting a recently searched word in my language dictionary application) and call something like:

```
 [SearchBar textDidChange: recentlySearchedWord]
```

but this simply does not work from anywhere in my code.

Please help me if you have some idea how to solve this.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you implement UISearchBar's delegate method `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` in your view controller (or any class) and you want to call that method from within the same class, which is what you want to do I'm assuming, you'd have to call

```
[self searchBar:SearchBar textDidChange:recentlySearchedWord];
```

with *SearchBar* being the instance of the UISearchBar you are referencing.

Comment: how do you do this in swift?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan you mean: searchBar(searchBar, textDidChange: recentlySearchedWord)

Answer (score 1):

textDidChange is not a class method.  So instead of calling:

```
[SearchBar textDidChange: recentlySearchedWord];
```

call

```
[self searchBar:mySearchBar textDidChange: recentlySearchedWord];
```

Or if textDidChange is in a different class, use the class instance insted of self.

Answer (score -1):

You could also possibly try using this code if it makes anything easier.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Input with icon:</p>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He didn't ask about html, you know!